# JavaScript setIntervall only runs once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
<script>

    function countdown(){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var countdown_html = $('.countdown').clone();
            var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 23, 2017 19:37:25").getTime();


            // Update the count down every 1 second

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
             var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            $('.num.days', countdown_html).text(days );
            $('.num.hours', countdown_html).text(hours );
            $('.num.minutes', countdown_html).text(minutes );
            $('.num.seconds', countdown_html).text(seconds );

            $('.countdown').countdown({until: <?php echo $date['to'] ?>, layout: countdown_html.html() });

        });
    }
var run = setInterval(countdown,1000);

</script>
```

This code only executes the countdown function once, after 1 second. I am trying to implement a simple countdown timer, extending a wordpress plugin that isn't compatible anymore. I am a total beginner with JavaScript, and all of the above is 100% Copy & Paste, but it all works, except the automated calling of the function.

Comment: Get rid of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ...` and you'll be fine. The way it is now, you're only *registering* an event once on every `1000ms` but obviously, that `DOMReady` event would only be triggered once. You better call `setInterval(countdown, 1000)` upon `$(document.ready)` though

Comment: You don't understand what `jQuery(document).ready` does.

Comment: @haim770 `ready` callbacks are executed right away when the page is already ready. It's weird, but not a problem.

Comment: What is `$('.countdown').countdown(…)`? Do you have a jQuery plugin loaded?

Comment: Possible solution: replace the ``` jQuery(document).ready(function($){``` line with this:```if (document.readyState !== 'complete') { return;}``` (and get rid of the ```});``` in the end, of course).

Comment: "*only executes the countdown function once*" - are you sure? Have you done some debugging (putting breakpoints or `console.log` statements in the function)? Or are you saying that the page updates only once?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any understanding of the code or JavaScript in general, I am just fiddling with our website at the moment since we don't have any JavaScript Developers on board. I can only say that all the stated possible solutions did not work out. Wrapping the the setIntervall within the .ready() however worked, as far as creating an alert popup each time. The functionality itself (updating the text in the html) however, doesn't.

Comment: I tested with cosole.log() and the time indeed decreases, apparently it's just the document that doesn't update..

Answer (score -1):

move your init function like this:

```
  <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        function countdown(){

            var countdown_html = $('.countdown').clone();
            var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 23, 2017 19:37:25").getTime();


            // Update the count down every 1 second

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
             var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            $('.num.days', countdown_html).text(days );
            $('.num.hours', countdown_html).text(hours );
            $('.num.minutes', countdown_html).text(minutes );
            $('.num.seconds', countdown_html).text(seconds );

            $('.countdown').countdown({until: <?php echo $date['to'] ?>, layout: countdown_html.html() });


    }
var run = setInterval(countdown,1000);
    });
</script>
```

`jQuery(document).ready` is only called once

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. When inserting alert("Test"); the popup indeed comes up every second, however the desired functionality of the updating text doesn't. So I guess now the problem is not the setIntervall anymore,but the functionality inside it, which somehow does not work the way expected, when called multiple times. Sadly I have no knowledge whatsoever with JavaScript.

Comment: you should open a new quesition and add the code. or create a fiddle...

Answer (score -2):

Since all your code is wrapped inside the `jQuery(document).ready()` method, it will be executed only when the document becomes ready and that can happen only once by definition.